# Any good Crash Reporting Services for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, crash, flurry

Right now we are using Flurry to gather crash reports from our users. The problem is that each crash is limited to 255 chars, and we can't see the complete stack trace. Is there a similar service out there that will allow us to see the full stack trace of the crashes?

Comment: I wrote a blog post about the different solutions available: [Quality Tracking/Crash reporters for Mobile Apps](http://nielsmouthaan.nl/quality-trackingcrash-reporters-for-mobile-apps/)

Answer (score 11):

Try out this one:

[Crittercism Crash Reporting System  for iOS](https://www.crittercism.com/)

It is really clean and easy to use.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 5):

Apple already does this for you.

Go to iTunesConnect, Manage Your Applications, View Details and then select the crash reports link.

[image]

You'll get crash reports broken down by operating system version which is really useful.

Comment: can you update this for ios8. i couldnt find this part

Comment: Unfortunately itunesconnect doesn't show all crash reports. It doesn't show anything unless there are a lot of reports.

Answer (score 5):

To take this list a bit further:

- [BugSense](http://www.bugsense.com/) is another bug tracking service for iOS, Android and WP7.
- [AirBrake](https://airbrake.io/) seems to be really nice and has plans from free (i.e. just one project, user,..) to extra large (i.e. 64 projects, users, ..).
- [Testflight](https://testflightapp.com/sdk/) additionally lets you distribute your beta apps without hassle.

Comment: The airbrake link has a browser security warning when I click on it, is it still correct?

Comment: Thanks @yochannah, updated the link (Airbrake changed to .io instead of .com)

Answer (score 2):

Try [Testflight SDK](https://testflightapp.com/sdk/doc). Includes your own logs as well. Make's it easier to track bugs down.

Comment: Actually, I've found the TestFlight SDK to be the most reliable crash reporting mechanism so far.  Ive only used it during testing phase so far for my kids apps as I don't leave it live.  I will however be leaving the SDK in for non-kids apps as their UI and symbolication is the best I've found.

Comment: Yes, this is a great framework

Answer (score 2):

FYI, BugSense have changed their plans somehow.  I was emailed this morning, and what was free is now $19 per month.  Way too pricey for indie developers that in some cases don't make much off their apps.

A point to note also is that to date, I have yet to get a sensible (iOS) stacktrace out of BugSense.  I get stacktraces, but their symbolication mechanism is broken so I have to manually work out where the problems are.  If the stacktraces worked, I think it would be a brilliant (though overpriced) product.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need any additional SDK's to view the crash raports. Apple gives you this functionality in their "iTunes Connect" portal. Here is how to access it:

- Log in to https://itunesconnect.apple.com
- go to "Manage Your Applications"
- choose your application, by clicking on it's name.
- click "View details" button under the Versions table.
- click "Crash Reports" link
- if you don't have reports yet, press "refresh"

That's it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Not fully reliable. Our app users are reporting crashes.. and here it shows none.

Comment: Usually iTunes connect doesn't display the errors until they reach a certain amount for a particular OS version

Comment: That is the stupidity of Apple.

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out Apple does hosts crash reports for you, although it usually only represent a tiny fraction of all the crashes your users are getting.

I personally use [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com) (free) for beta crash reports and [Exceptional](https://www.getexceptional.com) (9$/month per app) for production crash reports. Exceptional is really great, although a bit expensive. It groups together similar crash reports so you can quickly see what are the most recurrent crashes.

I also heard good things about [Hoptoad](http://airbrakeapp.com/pages/home) (recently renamed to Airbrake).